# Inherited entity item not recognized as entity?

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, inheritance, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to create a generic typed class, but am running into a problem. Here is my basic class definition:

```
public class QueueObject<T> where T : System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity
{
    public string LoadingMessage { get; set; }
    public System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery<T> Query { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to add instances of this class to a queue

```
private Queue<QueueObject<Entity>> _queue;
this._queue.Enqueue(new QueueObject<MyEntity> {Query = MyContext.GetMyEntitiesQuery(), LoadingMessage = "Loading some stuff"});
```

This doesn't work. I get an error saying that QueueObject cannont be converted to QueueObject. I don't understand because MyEntity inherits from Entity. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the same code in VB if it helps:

```
Public Class QueueObject(Of T As System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity)
    Public Property LoadingMessage As String
    Public Property Query As System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery(Of T)
End Class

Private _queue As Queue(QueueObject(Of Entity))
Me._queue.Enqueue(New QueueObject(Of MyEntity) With {.Query = MyContext.GetMyEntitiesQuery(), .LoadingMessage = "Loading some stuff..."})
```

Comment: Have you tried Private _queue As Queue(Of As System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity) OR Private _queue As Queue(Of QueueObject)

Comment: I can do queue of EntityQuery (non-typed), but when I dequeue the query I want to pass it into my Context.Load() method and it won't take a non-typed EntityQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure about the reason for the original error, but a possible solution was to make each entity implement an interface. Then make the QueueObject be of this interface type.

I ended up going another route so this ended up being irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your declaration of the queue as `Queue<Entity>`. I think what you want is:

```
Queue<QueueObject<MyEntity>> _queue;
```

That'll specifically fix your compile problem. Though that won't help you "genericise" your queue to contain QueueObjects that hold any other type of Entity. To fix that it'll take changes all the way up to your `GetMyEntitiesQuery()` to return a basic EntityQuery instead...

Where possible, I would work out which part your don't need to be generic and start from there. That is, where can you just let polymorphism do it's magic. For example, does it matter that the QueueObject's EntityQuery is strongly typed?

Comment: Good eye. However, that is how I did it. I just typed it wrong in the question. The thing I don't understand is my Context.GetMyEntitiesQuery() returns a EntityQuery<MyEntity> and it will work in the Context.Load() method seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422589(v=vs.91).aspx
but it won't work in my QueueObject defined the same way. Essentially all I am trying to do is have a queue of queries and Context.Load() each one as its dequeued.